# Function return type mismatching with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't understand it. I am knew to TypeScript and I am trying to stick to its recommendations as much as possible but this one makes no sense to me.

[image: See how TypeScript tells about an issue with the return type]

Reading the tip, I see the definition of type `EffectCallback` which is, among other things:

```
type EffectCallback = (() => void)
```

Just to see if it makes any difference, I put the *definition* of the type directly and as you can see, it doesn't trigger TypeScript anymore.

[image]

What am I missing?

And another thing is, according to what TypeScript tells me, `useEffect` expects an `EffectCallback`, which is at best a function that returns `void` as a parameter.

[image: TypeScript tells us <code>useEffect</code> expecs an EffectCallback]

The thing is that according to [React documentation about `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), I can pass a function that returns a function. React uses this function for cleanup purposes.

My guts tell me there is one small thing I can't get my finger on that would otherwise allow me to figure this out!

Comment: Well looks like `useEffect` is expecting it's first argument to *be* an `EffectCallback`, not a function that returns an `EffectCallback`. Note that the actual type for `EffectCallback` is `() => (void | (() => void | undefined));`, which does allow it to be a function that returns a function. But the returned function *should not itself be an `EffectCallback`*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first code example you have this:

```
(): EffectCallback => {
```

That means this is a function that returns an `EffectCallback`. However, that's not what `useEffect` is expecting. The function needs to **be** an `EffectCallback`, not return one. An `EffectCallback` is either a function that returns nothing, or a function that returns a teardown function.

In your second example, you move on to this:

```
(): (() => void) => {
```

Now you're saying it's a function that returns a teardown function. And a function which returns a teardown function is one of the legal ways to do an EffectCallback, so it matches.

---

Unless you're using a lint rule that requires explicit return types, i wouldn't bother doing explicit return types with `useEffect`. It's simpler to just do `() => {`, and if the code you write returns something that's illegal for `useEffect`, typescript will point that out.

Answer (score 2):

`EffectCallback` is the type of the function you pass to `useEffect`.

If you want to get the type of the clean up function of `useEffect` you can simply use `ReturnType<EffectCallback>`.

e.g.

```
useEffect((): ReturnType<EffectCallback> => {
    return (): void => {}
})
```

You can also take a look at the type `EffectCallback` and see what it is

```
type EffectCallback = () => (void | Destructor);

declare const UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY: unique symbol;

type Destructor = () => void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never };
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks for this answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if you're checking if the useEffect is still subscribed.

// Cancel subscription to useEffect.
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);

I had to use Nicholas's answer above to return a teardown function.